# JBoss 5.1.0 GA configuration for Oracle Data Guard

Tags: jboss, oracle

Can someone please point me to some tutorial or "how to" for configuring Jboss to work along with Oracle Data Guard. Motivation behind this is pretty standard, move some of the users to read from the "stand by" database. As this seems to be de facto industry standard i'm not have been able to find any tutorials and best practices on this.

Comment: Asking for a tutorial/how-to is not something we get thrilled about on this site. Have you consulted the documentation for Jboss?

Comment: No, i watched twelve episodes of Sopranos in a row and came here to bother you. I did, but i could not find any stuff. Maybe it's not there maybe i lack technical terms to better search into this issue but posting questions here is always my last option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short all i needed was something like [this](https://sites.google.com/site/mysitepeter/configuring-datasource-for-oracle10g---pedro-daz-robles). Key part here being definition of connection URL:

```
 <connection-url>
 jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=(load_balance=on)(failover=on)(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=node1-vip)(port=1521))(address=(
 protocol=tcp)(host=node2-vip)(port=1521)))(connect_data=(service_name=myservice.org.mx) (failover_mode=(type=select)(method=basic))))
 </connection-url>
```

Also in StandBy database there should be links to handle inserts.